# 「Google サイト」で作成したサイトをGoogle検索で表示させるには

Tags: google-search, google-sites

Google サイトでサイトを作成しました。

- サイトの構成としては以下です。

```
・Google サイトは新しいものを使用しております。
・サイト内に外部の別サイトにつながるリンクはありません。
・1ページのみのサイトで、別ページに飛ぶ(内部リンク?)もありません。
・カスタムドメインを使用せず、デフォルトのドメイン(https://sites.google.com/～のようなアドレスです。)
```

- その他の情報は以下です。

```
・作成してから1カ月以上は経過しておりますので、待てば表示される可能性は低いと考えています。
　(外部リンクがないこともあり、クロールが拾えていないのだと考えています。)
・`site:`でサイトを検索しましたが、表示されませんでした。
```

・`Google Search Console`にログイン、`URL プレフィックス`→`フルの URL を入力`→`続行`を選択し、
　登録を試みましたが、**カスタムドメインを取得しておらず**　`HTML ファイル`・`HTML タグ`・`Google Analytics`などのうち、
　どれを選びどのように登録すれば良いかが分からない状態です。

どなたかご教示いただけないでしょうか。
情報不足しておりましたら申し訳ございません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 外部リンクがないこともあり、クロールが拾えていないのだと考えています。

逆で、既にクロール済みの他のサイトからリンクされていないのでクロールされていないものと思われます。参考: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/links-crawlable?hl=ja

Google にページを手動で登録するには https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/ask-google-to-recrawl?hl=ja に書かれているように Google Search Console で検査したあとインデックス登録をリクエスト登録すれば良いです。このためには Google Search Console にサイトを登録する必要があり、これは Google Sites でカスタムドメインを利用しない場合は https://support.google.com/sites/answer/97459?hl=ja に書かれているように Google Analytics を利用する方法が使えます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

> 逆で、既にクロール済みの他のサイトからリンクされていないのでクロールされていないものと思われます。

なるほど他のサイトからリンクする必要があるのですね、
訂正ありがとうございます。

また、ご教示頂いた手順をもとに、
`Google Analytics のアカウントを作成` → `Google Search Console にログイン` → `URL プレフィックス` 
の手順を踏んだところ、** 所有権を自動確認しました。** という表示になりました。(相談前は確認に失敗しておりました。)

この状態で少し待ってみようかと思います。
おかげさまで進んだ感じがして安心しております。
nekketsuuu 様、ご丁寧に回答いただき本当にありがとうございました。